# Apache External access

Tags: apache-2.2, kerberos

I am wondering if anyone can help me.  I am trying to setup SSO.  I have it working inside a domain, where the kerberos ticket is passed and they sign on works and the user is able to login correctly.  If no kerberos ticket is present it requests that the user logs in via a manual login form.  However if I access the file from a location outside of the local domain e.g. home computer it presents me with a 403 error with no option to log in.

I have adjusted my .conf to various options with varying results of:

1. Having access inside domain with kerberos ticket working (auto/manual) but no external access
2. Having access externally without kerberos ticket and manual login inside domain.
3. Having access everywhere without any promps.

my conf is

```
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias example.com
 DocumentRoot /location/example/pub
 LogLevel debug
 <Directory "/location/example/pub">
    Allow from all
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from 127.0.0.0/8

    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "Kerberos Test"

    KrbMethodNegotiate on
    KrbMethodK5Passwd on
    KrbLocalUserMapping on
    KrbSaveCredentials on
    KrbVerifyKDC on
    KrbAuthoritative on
    KrbServiceName HTTP

    Krb5keytab /location.keytab
    KrbAuthRealm EXAMPLE.COM

    Require valid-user
    Satisfy Any

    ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
</Directory>
```

If I remove the deny it works from everywhere but does not allow any form of kerberos login.  When it is in place I get the required kerberos login (sso/manual) but I am getting a 403 from any location other than inside the domain.

Does anyone have any suggestions/ideas? as i'm all out.

Thanks.

Comment: fixed it by using the <Location > tags and set the locatiosn correctly inside of the htaccess